# change body color on slide change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change background-color on body to mix color on slide change but facing problem can anybody help me .  this is my function on slide change but do't know what mistake i am doing. my site url is http://krakenworldwide.com/destinations/`

```
    function imgbackground() {
        if (jQuery('.slide a').hasClass('a1')) {
            jQuery('body').css({
                'background-color': '#63bcf8',
                'background-image': 'none'
            });
        } else if (jQuery('.slide a').hasClass('a2')) {
            jQuery('body').css({
                'background-color': '#d7e5f2',
                'background-image': 'none'
            });
        } else if (jQuery('.slide a').hasClass('a3')) {
            jQuery('body').css({
                'background-color': '#a3cff4',
                'background-image': 'none'
            });
        } else if (jQuery('.slide a').hasClass('a4')) {
            jQuery('body').css({
                'background-color': '#fefefe',
                'background-image': 'none'
            });
        } else {
            jQuery('body').css({
                'background-color': '#fff',
                'background-image': 'none'
            });
        }
    }


    window.setInterval(function () {
        imgbackground()
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It will make it easier for others to read, and therefore more likely for you to get an answer.

Comment: have you added jquery-ui library in your page? animating background colors is not possible without jquery ui lib.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't have much time to sift through your code (it is all over the place) but I did notice a few things that might help you:

1. You are linking to 2 different versions of JQuery you have one link to version "...1.10.2" in your "wp-includes" folder and below that you are linking to version "...1.7.1.min.js" in your "wp-content" folder.  The lower one in the order will override the higher one.
2. You need to load your main JQuery library before all the other plug-ins so move whichever version you want above all other script links.
3. It looks like your slide function is changing the `display`, `z-index`, and `left` properties of each anchor tag within `<div class="slides-control"...>` but the classes for each individual anchor tag remain the same so the function you wrote above won't work because `'.slide a'` always has a class of `a1` and it always has a class of `a2` and so on.
4. There are many ways to accomplish what you are looking for but you might try assigning an id to each anchor tag within `<div class="slides-control"...>`. Then assigning a color to your background based on which anchor tag has `display:block;`.

So you code would look something like this:

```
function imgbackground() {
    if ($('#anchor1').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('body').css({
            'background-color': '#63bcf8',
            'background-image': 'none'
        });
    } else if ($('#anchor2').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('body').css({
            'background-color': '#d7e5f2',
            'background-image': 'none'
        });
    } else if ($('#anchor3').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('body').css({
            'background-color': '#a3cff4',
            'background-image': 'none'
        });
    } else if ($('#anchor4').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('body').css({
            'background-color': '#fefefe',
            'background-image': 'none'
        });
    } else {
        $('body').css({
            'background-color': '#fff',
            'background-image': 'none'
        });
    }
}
```

I also didn't see anywhere where you are calling your function.

- You need to either do it the body: `<body onload="imgbackground()">...</body>`
- Or use the JQuery .ready() method:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // your "imgbackground" function here
  }
  ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would start by cleaning up your code and the order in which you are linking to your external files in the `<head>` tag.  I also recommend you do some debugging.  I noticed that you have at least 16 errors in your `base.js` file.  Just open your page in Chrome then right click > inspect element and play around with all the options. I'm far from an expert but that's what I do! Cheers!